# Suddenly got quri.parser::parse-scheme-string is undefined

Tags: common-lisp, quicklisp

I was a happy user of Dexador. Suddenly, a simple `dex:get<url>` throws me a

```
quri.parser::parse-scheme-string is undefined
```

error.

Trying `(dex:get url)`:

```
0: ("undefined function")
 1: (quri.parser::parse-uri-string #<unavailable argument> :start #<unavailable argument> :end #<unavailable argument>)
2: (quri.uri:uri "http://1337x.to/sort-search/sintel/seeders/desc/1/" :start 0 :end nil)
3: (dexador.backend.usocket:request #<unavailable argument> #<unavailable &REST argument> :method #<unused argument> :version #<unused argument> :content #<unavailable argument> :headers #<unavailable ar.
```

It seems related to my environment. I *think* it popped out after I downgraded my QL version (because of a Slime error).

**edit**: I once accepted this error on the debugger, it doesn't pop-up anymore.

It's weird: neither Dexador nor Quri were modified recently. It used to work.

Also, I greped Dexador and Quri, in my QL's local dist projects, to find this function, and it only appears once in Quri. It is not even a defined function, so how could it even work ? (given the package uses cl, quri.error and quri.util) https://github.com/fukamachi/quri/blob/83f3b8612be826b602f3584acac1b82691a141e6/src/parser.lisp#L96

I deleted the fasl files found in my project.

Anyway, how would you approach this problem ?

I still don't want to upgrade Quicklisp, Slime didn't release a new version.

**edit**: I upgraded QL, then deleted `~/quicklisp/` and re-installed it, deleted all `~/.cache/common-lisp`: the same.

thanks.

SBCL Debian 1.2.4 (installed 1.4.13, couldn't load my project with another ironclad error).
Quicklisp dist "2018-04-30".

I also asked in an issue https://github.com/fukamachi/dexador/issues/61#issuecomment-433672052

Comment: The function seems to be defined with the macro [`DEFUN-WITH-ARRAY-PARSING` on line 281](https://github.com/fukamachi/quri/blob/83f3b8612be826b602f3584acac1b82691a141e6/src/parser.lisp#L281).

Comment: I'd guess that you don't have a consistent quicklisp dist version state on your system, and thus incompatible versions of these two libraries.

Comment: Installing both dexador and quri as local projects doesn't help… would you delete some cache files, what would you try ?

Comment: Deleting dexador and quri's fasl files from `~/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-xx/path/to/quicklisp/local-projects` didn't help. Deleting all sbcl cache neither.

Comment: Upgrading to the latest quicklisp neither. S.t.u.c.k.

Comment: Deleted `~/quicklisp/`, re-installed QL, deleted all `~/.cache/common-lisp/`: still the same. Stuck bis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro used `format` to intern new symbols, and I set `*print-case*` to `:downcase` in my .sbclrc.

There's a fix: https://github.com/fukamachi/quri/pull/24

Deleting the fasl cached in `~/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-xx/quri/` and quickloading quri  was then enough to have the function back.